# Validation issue with Microdata: "The itemprop attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item."

Tags: html, schema.org, w3c-validation, microdata

Can somebody help setting up `itemprop` problem we are having at validation? The result is:

> Error: The itemprop attribute was specified, but the element is not a property of any item.

This is how to markup starts:

```html
<html itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" lang="en">
```

Then later on it follows as:

```html
<img itemprop="author" src=".../>
<h1 itemprop="name" style="...>
......
<div itemprop="articleSection" class="...>
<div itemprop="articleBody" class="...>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each property (`itemprop`) has to belong to an item (`itemscope`). The error message tells you that you have a property for which that is not the case.

It seems that your `mainEntity` property does not belong to an item. You probably want to use [`WebPage`](http://schema.org/WebPage):

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>…</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <article itemprop="mainEntity" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article">
    </article>
  </body>
</html>
```

As the [`mainEntity`](http://schema.org/mainEntity) has an inverse property, [`mainEntityOfPage`](http://schema.org/mainEntityOfPage), you could also use a different structure, which would make sense if you don’t have any other properties for `WebPage`:

```html
<html itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Article" lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>…</title>
    <link itemprop="mainEntityOfPage" href="the-URL-of-your-page" />
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```